# VM Player running Ubuntu only logs to guest session

Tags: linux

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on VM Player. Everything worked perfectly well, but all of a sudden, after launching, Ubuntu no longer logins with my username. Instead, I only have Guest Session. If I go to switch user, it is the same story. The /etc/shadow file displays my username though, as expected (among the rest).

Running su username returns no permission. Is there any other way for me to retrieve the account? Can I switch from the terminal to my username in a Guest Session?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your automatic login settings have changed.  You can change this by going to System - Administration - Login Window.  You will be prompted for Admin rights, which is your user account probably.  Once you authenticate, you check 'enable automatic login' and enter your account.  Or the file to edit is /etc/lightdm.conf.

With that said, try not to use an administrator account when using your computer on a daily basis.  Good practice is to use a normal user account on a daily basis.